# wxRibbonGallery shows up blank even with bitmap appended to it

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I created a `wxRibbonGallery` and appended a bitmap to it, but whenever I load the executable, it is nothing but a white screen. I did some testing by using the `bitmap` bitmap to create a `wxBitmapButton` which showed up as expected. I also added a line to print the number of items in the gallery, and it printed "1" as expected. Here's a
[picture with my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Eq2I.png)

Comment: You should check if the image size meets the requirements for a ribbon.

Comment: @macroland How would I do that? Is it somewhere in the documentation?
The image is 640 x 480

Comment: didnt seem to be the case anyway. I resized it to 50x38, but it still doesnt work

Comment: @JodiMcJohnson, the image size should be small. Something like 16x16 or 32x32. Check `ribbon` sample for details.

Comment: @Igor yeah that wont work for my use case unfortunately, but thanks! I've been slamming my head against the wall for a while with this one
would you possibly know a better way to make a grid of images that scale depending on the size of the window (like a wxGridSizer)

Comment: @JodiMcJodson, do you have a sketch f what you are after? Can you post it here or make `imgur` link? But I thought you are talking abut the ribbon bar. The one you see on top of MS Office product... But now I have my doubts - that's why the request for a sketch.

Comment: @JodiMcJodson, also, what is your platform and wx version?

Comment: @igor here's an imgur link: [link](https://imgur.com/BOwJIZ7)
I just want it to display the images in a grid like so. Plus maybe have a way to cycle between pages if they don't fully fit on the screen

my platform is linux (but ideally it should be cross platform since that's most of the reason im using wxWidget) and my wx version is 3.0.0

Comment: @JodiMcJodson, please try with either 3.1.5 or current master. Is bitmap have any alpha channel? Is it loaded correctly? Is you screen a HighDPI one?

Comment: @igor I am on 3.1.5 according to `wx-config --version` actually. Yes the PNG has an alpha channel, is that what is causing the issue? And no, my screen is not HighDPI

Comment: removed the alpha channel, still doesn't show up